# Joint distribution of top order statistics of two independent random samples of Pareto distribution

Tags: order-statistics, pareto-distribution

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ and $Y_1,...,Y_n$ are all independent copies of a standard Pareto random variable. For each of the 'two' random samples we can denote the order statistics $X_{n:n} \geq X_{n-1:n} \geq \ldots \geq X_{1:n}$, and, $Y_{n:n} \geq Y_{n-1:n} \geq \ldots \geq Y_{1:n}$.

Suppose we take the top 3 order statistics from the first sample $X_{n:n}, X_{n-1:n}, X_{n-2:n}$ and just $Y_{n-2:n}$ from the other sample. If we are given that $Y_{n-2:n}>X_{n-3:n}$, is there any way to characterize the joint distribution of the order statistics of $(X_{n:n}, X_{n-1:n}, X_{n-2:n}, Y_{n-2:n})=(\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3, \xi_4)$? It is probably not true, but somehow I am wondering if we have the equality in distribution
$$(\xi_{4:4},\xi_{3:4}, \xi_{2,4}, \xi_{1:4})\overset{d}{=}(Z_{n+1:n+1}, Z_{n:n+1}, Z_{n-1:n+1}, Z_{n-2:n+1}) \qquad \mid Y_{n-2:n}>X_{n-3:n} $$
for the order statistics $Z_{n+1:n+1} \geq \ldots \geq Z_{1:n+1}$ of another random sample of the Pareto distribution.

Comment: I wouldn't expect such an equality, because $Y_{n-2:2}$ could be in any of the four possible positions.

Comment: @whuber For my understanding, what in particular makes that $Y_{n-2:n}$ can end up in any of the four possible positions not compatible with the equality? Do you see any other way to characterize their joint distribution?

Comment: The condition $Y_{n-2:n} \gt X_{n-3:n}$ means the top $X$ values tend to be unusually small.  For medium to large size $n$ this effect ought to be observable and suggests the distributions of the $\xi_{4-k:4}$ will have shorter upper tails than the $Z_{n+1-k:n+1}.$

Comment: Why do you want the joint distribution for four statistics? Anything you might want to calculate from the joint distribution is probably easier to calculate in some other way.